# Generating Test Dataset For Recommendation System from existing data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, recommendation-engine

I am trying to build a recommender system using the scala API for apache-spark.

I have a dataset of the form (User,Product,Rating) for all items that all the users have rated. In order to give recommendations, I need a dataset of the form (U,P) with all U,P pairs that are not present in my initial dataset . (user,product pairs for all the products that each user has not bought). anyone know of any straight forward way to do this ?

ps- You can assume there are no other users or items apart from the ones in the initial set.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial could be very helpful for you:

http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/big-data-mini-course/movie-recommendation-with-mllib.html